# When parsing a string, it gives a syntax error

Tags: javascript, json

There is a JSON that gives a syntax error when `JSON.parse` But if you check it for syntax in online services, then there is no error. How can I parse these lines and remove the escaping quotes?

```
{"bubbles":false,"cancelBubble":false,"cancelable":false,"currentTarget":{},"data":"{\"id\":5,\"channel\":\"private_Mgfj2W80CIQDhgu4SjOeQci3LLVZdDD-dcY339RIZP0\",\"text\":{\"content\":{\"m\":\"alert_fired\",\"p\":{\"fire_id\":14567916611,\"sound_file\":null,\"symbol\":\"FX:EURUSD\",\"cross_interval\":false,\"popup\":false,\"message\":\"BUY\",\"alert_id\":786895183,\"sound_duration\":0,\"fire_time\":\"2023-03-31T15:20:00Z\",\"name\":\"test: при любом вызове функции alert()\",\"resolution\":\"1\",\"bar_time\":\"2023-03-31T15:20:00Z\"},\"id\":\"57wy-8828807\"},\"channel\":\"pricealerts\"}}","defaultPrevented":false,"eventPhase":2,"lastEventId":"","origin":"wss://pushstream.tradingview.com","path":[],"ports":[],"returnValue":true,"source":null,"srcElement":{},"target":{},"timeStamp":44258.30000000028,"type":"message"}
{"bubbles":false,"cancelBubble":false,"cancelable":false,"currentTarget":{},"data":"{\"id\":6,\"channel\":\"private_Mgfj2W80CIQDhgu4SjOeQci3LLVZdDD-dcY339RIZP0\",\"text\":{\"content\":\"{\\\"m\\\":\\\"event\\\",\\\"p\\\":{\\\"id\\\":14567916611,\\\"aid\\\":786895183,\\\"fire_time\\\":1680276000,\\\"bar_time\\\":1680276000,\\\"sym\\\":\\\"FX:EURUSD\\\",\\\"res\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"desc\\\":\\\"BUY\\\",\\\"snd_file\\\":\\\"alert\\/fired\\\",\\\"snd\\\":false,\\\"popup\\\":false,\\\"cross_int\\\":false,\\\"name\\\":\\\"test: при любом вызове функции alert()\\\",\\\"snd_duration\\\":0}}\",\"channel\":\"alert\"}}","defaultPrevented":false,"eventPhase":2,"lastEventId":"","origin":"wss://pushstream.tradingview.com","path":[],"ports":[],"returnValue":true,"source":null,"srcElement":{},"target":{},"timeStamp":44261.30000000028,"type":"message"}
```

Comment: The string value of the `data` member has unescaped quotes, it must be `"data":"{\"id\"...` rather than `"data":"{"id"...`.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them. What is the exact error? What do you exactly run to get to that error...

Comment: Why is that JSON escaped so much? Can't you fix it at source?

Comment: Error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 86

Just on the "data" parameter, an error appears

Comment: I intercept these jsion lines from the websocket of one service. Maybe it's some kind of protection against parsing? ... although it is unlikely, since in one of the online services for checking the syntax of jsion, parsing was successfully carried out and even escaping quotes was removed.


What needs to be corrected in the jsion line?
In principle, I can first correct the jsion, and then do the parsing.
... although this is dancing with a tambourine.
And this way you can do string parsing without using jsion :(